# Sitecore 7 enabling LINQ extension

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore7

This is what I have so far

```
using Sitecore.ContentSearch;
using Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq;
using Sitecore.ContentSearch.SearchTypes;
using Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq.Utilities;
using Sitecore.Search;

using (var context = SearchManager.GetIndex(searchIndexName).CreateSearchContext())
{   

}
```

In the context I don't have a function **context.GetQueryable()**
. Can someone please tell me what am I missing.

Comment: Have you tried to write it anyway and see if it works? Don't always rely on the intellisense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
//Create a Search Context to the "indexname" Index (could be SOLR/Lucene/something else)
using (var context = new ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("indexname").CreateSearchContext()) 
{
 //LINQ Query
 var query = context.GetQueryable<SomeType>.Where(i => i.Name.StartsWith("Something"));

}
//Disposal due to IDisposable
```

Also you can check this [link](http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/Sitecore-7-Development-Team/Posts/2013/04/Sitecore-7-Patterns-for-Global-Search-Context-Reuse.aspx)

Comment: I tried it does not work Error 'Sitecore.Search.IndexSearchContext' does not contain a definition for 'GetQueryable' and no extension method 'GetQueryable' accepting a first argument of type 'Sitecore.Search.IndexSearchContext' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 2):

Your using statement refers to the `SearchManager` class which is from the `Sitecore.Search` namespace in `Sitecore.Kernel`.

You actually need to use the `ContentSearchManager` class which is from the "
`Sitecore.ContentSearch` namespace in `Sitecore.ContentSearch`.